# Set of functions is linear subspace of $C(I_n)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $S\subset C(I_n)$ (where $C(I_n)$ is the space of continuous functions of the $n$-dimensional unit cube) be the set of finite sums which can be written in the form
>   $$G(x) = \sum_{j=1}^N \alpha_j\sigma (y_j^Tx+\theta_j)$$
>   for some continuous function $\sigma$.
>
> Clearly, $S$ is a linear subspace of $C(I_n)$.

Why is it clear that $S$ is a linear subspace? I can see that the zero vector is in there, as we can choose, all $\alpha$s to be $0$, and I can see that it is scaling (from the distributive property), but why should it be linear?

If $G(x)$ and $H(x)$ can be written in that form for some $\sigma$, why should $(G+H)(x)$?

Original text from [here](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~gvc/Cybenko_MCSS.pdf) (page 306, according to the original numbering)

Comment: I'm not sure where you see the difficulty. Maybe it's this: Note that $N$ in this context can be any natural number $N$. So if $G$ has such a representation with $N$ terms, and $H$ with $M$ terms, then $G+H$ admits such a representation with at most $N+M$ terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G, H \in S$. We may write $$G(x) = \sum_{j=1}^N\alpha_j \sigma(y_j^Tx +\theta_j) \textrm{ , } H(x) = \sum_{k=1}^M \beta_k \sigma(z_k^Tx + \zeta_k)$$ Now set $\alpha_{N+k} = \beta_k$,$y_{N+k} = z_k$, $\theta_{N+k} = \zeta_k$ and we get $$(G+H)(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{N+M}\alpha_j \sigma(y_j^Tx +\theta_j)$$ which lies in $S$. I'm sure you can verify the other property.